# How to add string to an array list in c#

Tags: c#

I have a list and a string

```
var Resnames= new List<string>();
string name = "something";
```

I want to append string to it like

```
   Resnames  += name;
```

How can I do it

Comment: If you want to do it like that, why not just use a `string`?

Comment: I want to add many strings to the list and I want to display the list finally, How can I display the list. If I have more than 2 strings in the list

Comment: you can use the foreach to loop through the list and display them

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you are using [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) (not a legacy fixed-size array) you able to use [List.Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method:

```
resourceNames.Add(name);
```

If you want to add an item after the instantiation of a list instance you can use object initialization (since C# 3.0):

```
var resourceNames = new List<string> { "something", "onemore" };
```

Also you might find useful [List.AddRange()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method as well

```
var resourceNames = new List<string>();
resourceNames.Add("Res1");
resourceNames.Add("Res2");

var otherNames = new List<string>();
otherNames.AddRange(resourceNames);
```

Answer (score 10):

Just as simple as that:

```
Resnames.Add(name);
```

BTW: VisualStudio is your friend! By typing a `.` after Resnames it would have helped you.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the string to array list like this,

```
var Resnames= new List<string>();
string name = "something";
 Resnames.Add(name);


foreach (var item in Resnames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add String to List this way:

```
var ListName = new List<string>();

string StringName = "YourStringValue";

ListName.Add(StringName);
```

Comment: Is there anything new in comparison to the accepted and correct answer?